# Nonlinearity in OLS-models

Tags: regression, logistic, nonlinear-regression, multinomial-distribution, assumptions

I have a question connected to the OLS-Model's assumption of Linearity between parameters. What should be done if the assumption is not fulfilled?

My second question is if I can use multinomial logistic regression in case of non-linearity between parameters?

Comment: By "OLS" do you mean "linear regression"? Could you write a little bit more to get us more details about your problem?

Comment: It's linearity *in* parameters, not *between*, if I am not mistaken. If the assumption is not fulfilled, you may try to rearrange the model so that it becomes fulfilled. E.g. $y=x^{\beta} \cdot \varepsilon$ is not linear in $\beta$ but it could be replaced by $log(y)=\beta log(x)+log(\varepsilon)$ which is linear in $\beta$. To answer your second question more detailed information is needed.